# divide (split) the line into segments of arbitrary length each. (short at begining wide at the end)

Tags: java, algorithm

Assume there is a line `(1, 30)` (float x = 30)
I need to split it into segments, each next segment should be wider than previous one, and the last segment should be X times wider than first one.

I have idea first split line into equal parts and than increase next and decrease previous until two conditions reached: 
- first segment is shorter than last X times
- each segment (except first) is wider than previous for the same multiplier

```
    //input:
    int lineDimension = 30;
    int numberOfSegments = 5;
    int step = 1;

    float[] splitLineIntoSegments(float lineDimension, int numberOfSegments, float differenceBetweenFirstAndLastSegmentMultiplicator, float step) {
      float[] result = new float[numberOfSegments];
      //first split into equal segments
      for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSegments; i++) {
        result[i] = lineDimension / numberOfSegments;
      }
      //increase each next value untill difference reached
      do {
        for (int ii = 0; ii < numberOfSegments; ii++) {
          if (result[ii]-step<=0)
            return result;
            if (ii>numberOfSegments/2){
              result[ii] += step;
            }
            else result[ii] -= step;
        }
      }
      while ((float)result[numberOfSegments] / (float)result[0] > differenceBetweenFirstAndLastSegmentMultiplicator);

      return result;
    }

float [] res = splitLineIntoSegments(lineDimension,numberOfSegments,2,step);
```

as the result it should be 4,5,6,7,8

There is a better way to do it ?

Comment: What is a "line (1, 30)" ???

Comment: line could be distanse or something else. It means begining = 1 end = 30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ratios must be constant, let `r`, the relative lengths of the segments are `1`, `r`, `r²`, `r³`, … `r^(n-1)` for `n` parts and this sums to `(r^n-1) / (r-1)`. We also have `X = r^(n-1)`, giving `r = X^(1/(n-1))`.

If the length of the line segment is `L`, the parts are

```
L.r^k.(r-1) / (r^n-1)
```

E.g. for `4` parts and `X=27/8`, we have `r=3/2` and the parts are `8/65`, `12/65`, `18/65`, and `27/65` of `L`.

---

If the ratios needn't be constant and the parts are proportional to some given numbers `Rk` (such that `X=R[n-1]/R0`), take the sum `R` and use

```
L.Rk / R
```

Comment: Oh, mathematics, where would I be without you!

Answer (score 0):

You can force a simple arithmetic sequence for this.
Start with the problem parameters:

```
N = quantity of segments
X = scale factor: segment[N-1] / segment[0]
L = length of line
```

First, find the required mean:

```
mean = L / N
```

Now, we need the first and last terms to average to the mean.  Let `a` be the length of the first segment, currently unknown.  Solve for `a`

```
(a + X*a) / 2 = mean
 a = 2*mean / (1+X)
```

You now have the first (`a`) and last (`X*a`) terms, and the quantity of terms.  Now it's trivial to find the common difference:

```
d = (X*a - a) / (N-1)
```

Your sequence of segments is now

```
[ a + i*d for 0 <= i < N ]    // i being a sequence of integers
```